# 1-vs-1 comparisons from multi-player games

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let's say we have a dataframe like the following one.

```
Games    Players    Score
0            Foo      100
             Bar       10
             Baz        5
1           Blah       30
             Bar       10
             Foo        2
2            Foo       40
             Fes        5
             ...
```

I am hoping to process it to build a new dataframe (matrix), where we have:

```
pairwise_comparisons.loc[A, B] = W / T
```

with

```
W = # of games where A ended up with higher score than B
T = # of games in which they both participated
```

How can I approach this problem?

For example, using only the data shown above, we would populate the matrix as follows:

```
pairwise_comparisons.loc['Foo', 'Bar'] = 1/2
```

because `Foo` and `Bar` played against each other in Games `0` and `1` (2 games) and `Foo` won 1 time (Game `0`), so W/T = 1/2.

---

I could of course loop manually through each pair of players and compare their score, on every game, but this would probably be slow. Any ideas for how to vectorize the solution?

---

A variant of the above is when we are trying to compute `weighted_comparisons[A, B]`  where we could store the median difference in score between A and B in the games in which they both participated.

Comment: I think we should remove the `python-3.6` tag unless there is some issue *specific* to 3.6...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***setup***

```
s = pd.Series({
        (0, 'Bar'): 10,
        (0, 'Baz'): 5,
        (0, 'Foo'): 100,
        (1, 'Bar'): 10,
        (1, 'Blah'): 30,
        (1, 'Foo'): 2,
        (2, 'Fes'): 5,
        (2, 'Foo'): 40
    })
```

---

```
df = s.unstack()
v = df.values
m, n = v.shape
nrng = np.arange(n)

# who played who
played = (~np.isnan(v))
played_3d = played.reshape(m, 1, n) & played.reshape(m, n, 1)
played_3d[:, nrng, nrng] = False

# who beat who
scores = np.where(played, v, -1)
winners = np.where(
    played_3d,
    scores.reshape(m, 1, n) > scores.reshape(m, n, 1),
    0
)

# how many times have we played eachother
games_played = (played_3d).sum(0)
games_won = winners.sum(0)

pairwise = np.empty((n, n), dtype=np.float)
pairwise.fill(np.nan)
r, c = np.where(games_played != 0)
pairwise[r, c] = games_won[r, c] / games_played[r, c]
pairwise_comparisons = pd.DataFrame(pairwise, df.columns, df.columns).stack()

pairwise_comparisons.loc['Foo', 'Bar']

0.5
```

Comment: Less talk, more code.  Apologies for lack of commentary.